# Testing jest unit test and always get undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

let's I have the following functional component in React

```
const TestComponent = ({ name, ...props }) => {


  return (
    <div>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
};

TestComponent.propTypes = {
  name: T.object,
  classes: T.object,
};

export default TestComponent
```

on my test i have this

```
describe('Test component ', () => {
    it("name should match", () => {
        const obj ={
            name: "Test",
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent name={obj}/>);
        expect(wrapper.name).toEqual({
            name: "Test",
        })
    });
});
```

when i run npm test i keep getting wrapper is undefined

```
    Expected: {"name": "Test"}
    Received: undefined

      35 |         };
      36 |         const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent name={obj}/>);
    > 37 |         expect(wrapper.name).toEqual(obj)
         |                                 ^
      38 |     });
      39 | });
      40 |
```

I'm trying to match both object but I'm not sure why i keep getting undefined despite i already sent the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [.props() => Object](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html#props--object) API of enzyme. E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import TestComponent from './';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('61087595', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const obj = {
      name: 'Test',
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent name={obj} />);
    expect(wrapper.props().children).toEqual({ name: 'Test' });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61087595/index.test.tsx (7.805s)
  61087595
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.868s, estimated 10s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61087595